# Create an action with a class method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I would like to create a custom action inside a controller with a class method. But is it possible ?

I would look like:

```
class HellosController < ActionController::Base
  def self.index
  end
end
```

The problem then is that, how can we access it... I tried this:

```
get 'hello/'     => 'hellos.index'
```

But it's not a success.

> ArgumentError: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.

I know it is not from the Rails conventions, but if you have some ideas, you're welcome.

Comment: I don't know why you are doing it, but i think class methods should be in your model and you call them in you controller

Comment: Interesting. But how can I do if I want to have this method inside the controller (as all classical MVC frameworks)?

Comment: Well, you `self.index` need to be called by `index` action so routes work as stated by @Jared

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bad idea, or at least unconventional, to use a class method this way in a controller, but you could try something like this ..

```
class HellosController < ActionController::Base
  def self.index
  end

  def index
    self.class.index
  end
end
```

Don't say I didn't warn you when you try to start using instance variables :)

Comment: Thanks @Jared. But is it possible to build a route from routes.rb to this class method? (without using the instance method...)

Comment: ".. is it possible to .. route from .. to [a] class method?"  I've never seen it done.  See [AbstractController::Base.action_methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb)

Comment: Well, I guess, you can overwrite [`self.action_methods`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L78) and [`process_action`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L197) or [`action_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L212) for your `HellosController` and handle your special case there. But that seems like an overly-complicated solution to a problem that should be probably fixed at the design level (why do you have to do use class methods?).

Comment: Because collections' methods should be class methods, and resources' methods should be instance methods. Thus, index action could be self.get and show could be get. This way the OO stack is fully exploited.

Comment: @Zagzag.. to say "collection methods should be class methods" is an interesting idea, in fact it's a classic idea in the model layer.  However, it would be a fundamental change to the controller layer.  I expect there are technical reasons why rails requires a controller to be instantiated before processing an action.